# SQL Server 2008 R2 Transactional Replication into DB2/AS400 Creating Table Names and Fields wrapped with Quotes

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, db2-400

I'm trying to setup a push subscription from SQL Server 2008 R2 into DB2/AS400 and we're noticing that the tables on the DB2 side have both the table name and the field names wrapped with quotes. I assume it has something to do with QUOTED IDENTIFIER. How do I update the replication to not include these quotes? I assume I need to go low-level and modify the scripts as I do not see any setting through the replication wizards in SSMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much Googling I found out that I could disable quoted identifiers (which was translating from brackets to double quotes by default) by adding the "-QuotedIdentifier" argument with no value to the command line for the Distribution Agent. Once that was added, the replication worked without adding the double quotes.

[How to: View and Modify Replication Agent Command Prompt Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151326(v=sql.105).aspx)

[Replication Distribution Agent Parameter Listing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147328.aspx)